# Problem understanding the concept of principal ideal

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals

Definition of **Principal ideal**:

> Let $R$ be a commutative ring with unity and let $a \in R$ . The set $\langle a\rangle  = \{ra\mid r \in R\}$ is an ideal of $R$ called the *principal ideal generated by a*.

**Doubt**

What is the principal ideal in case of a subset of $R[x]$ (set of all polynomials with real coefficients) with constant term zero.

$A=\langle x\rangle $ will work but I actually don't understand what $\langle x\rangle$ mean here.
I think

$$A=\{f(x) \in R[x]\mid f(0)=0\}.$$

How all these things fit together?

Comment: You wrote yourself what $\langle x\rangle $ means just above it.

Comment: Ok. What if $\angle x^2+1\angle$ means then ?

Comment: Still, you have the definition right there, so I am not sure what you are really asking about.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft $<x^2+1>={ f(x^2+1)|f(x) \in R[x]}$.

Comment: Sorry if i am not clear.

Comment: You would make things more clear for yourself if you stop writing $f(x)$ for the polynomial $f$, since that makes it hard to tell the difference between evaluating $f$ at $x^2+1$ and multiplying $f$ by $x^2+1$.

Comment: Ok.Thanks ......

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\langle x\rangle$ is the set of all polynomials that can be written as a multiple of the polynomial $f(x)=x$. Let's take a look at your example:

Every polynomial $f\in R[x]$ with $f(0)=0$ can be written as $f(x)=g(x)x$ for some $g\in R[x]$. Vice versa, every polynomial of the form $f(x)=g(x)x$ satisfies $f(0)=0$. Therefore $\langle x\rangle = \{f\in R[x]\;|\;f(0)=0)\}$.

Comment: Ok. What if $\angle x^2+1\angle$ means then ?

Comment: It is the set of all polynomials that can be written as a multiple of the polynomial $x^2+1$. For example, $x^4+x^2=(x^2+1)x^2$ is such a polynomial, whereas for example $x$ or $x^2$ cannot be written in that form.

Comment: I get it now . Thanks.